# How do I pass abstract class as parameter for instance of type?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

So I have a type called `FunBond`, with a default constructor like this

```
public FunBond(int id,
            string name,
            Currency currency,
            double notional,
            DateTime maturityDate,
            List<CashFlowWithDate> couponCashFlows,
            DayCounter dayCounter)
            : base(id, name, notional, InstrumentType.FixedRateBond,  currency, maturityDate, dayCounter)
{ 
...
}
```

And `DayCounter` is an abstract class

```
public abstract class DayCounter
{
    public abstract string Name();
    public abstract double YearFraction(DateTime d1, DateTime d2);
    public abstract int DayCount(DateTime d1, DateTime d2);
}
```

Now my question is, what am I supposed to supply as a `DayCounter` to generate an instance of a `FunBond`? I can specify the id, name, currency, ... etc. etc. to pass as parameters to `FunBond`, but what is `DayCounter` supposed to be? I can't create an instance of it, and I can't supply it with anything I don't think... I thought I would need another class deriving from my abstract class to provide to `FunBond`, so I think I misunderstand something fundamentally.

Comment: You need to check which types derive from `DayCounter` which are instance classes that you can allocate. Or, perhaps the API requires *you* to derive from `DayCounter` and supply the implementation. Not sure as there's not enough context.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Hmm yeah that's what I thought, but I hadn't touched C# for a while so I thought I must be going crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The constructor is declaring that it requires an parameter of type `DayCounter`. Since `DayCounter` is an abstract class then you need to pass an instance of a class that derives from `DayCounter`.

That does not mean that you need to change the constructor parameter type, just pass an instance of a derived type.

The reason that someone defines a parameter of an abstract type is to allow polymorphism and loose coupling. You can have different derived classes of `DayCounter`, each behaving differently (as long as they adhere to the *contract* of `DayCounter`). And `FunBond` can speak to instances of such classes without knowing how they internally work. As far as `FunBond` is concerned, it is speaking to an object that adheres to the contract of `DayCounter`, but doesn't care how it internally implemented.

Comment: Many thanks, I see the purpose as well now. Some digging eventually found a set of classes of daycounters deriving from DayCounter I hadn't seen.

Comment: How would one know what are possible  derived classes without digging into abstract class or finding its references?

Comment: @mko, the IDE can help you. For example, in Visual Studio, you can right click on the class name and select 'Go To Implementations'.

Answer (score 0):

The question says:

> I thought I would need another class deriving from my abstract class
>   to provide to FunBond

That is correct - you need to create a concrete class from the abstract.

```
// Your derived class
public class WeekdayCounter : DayCounter
{
    public override string Name() { return "Weekday" }
    public override double YearFraction(DateTime d1, DateTime d2) { return 0.0; }
    public override int DayCount(DateTime d1, DateTime d2) { return 0; }
}

// Create a FunBond
WeekdayCounter c = new WeekdayCounter();  // **derived class**

FunBond yay = new FunBond(id,
                          name,
                          currency,
                          notional,
                          maturityDate,
                          couponCashFlows,
                          c);   // **WeekdayCounter, which is a DayCounter**
```